# Why $cordovaImagePicker plug in is crashing on Marshmallow?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am integration $cordovaImagePicker and it is working fine on kit kat and lollipop but recently I have installed the same app it is crashing on Marshmallow.
Below is the code I am using:

```
$cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options).then(function (results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        $scope.imagePath = results[i];
    }
}, function(error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content://media/external/images/media from pid=10669, uid=10319
>   requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or
>   grantUriPermission()
>                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:605)
>                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
>                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:211)
>                                                       at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
>                                                       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)

Any help?

Comment: I thinnk plugin is missing run time permission for higher android version.

Answer (score 1):

After spending some more time, I have figured these things out that Android Marshmallow has different mechanism of permission it asks for permission at run time so it needs to be catered. Below is the code

```
var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
permissions.hasPermission(permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
            function(status) {
               if (status.hasPermission) {
                   $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options).then(function (results) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                            $scope.imagePath = results[i];
                        }
                    }, function(error) {
                          console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));    // In case of error
                    });
                } else {
                  //permission is not granted case, now preparing for granting permission
                    permissions.requestPermission(
                        permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        function(status) {
                          if(!status.hasPermission) {
                            console.log();
                          }
                        },
                        function(status) {
                            console.log();
                        }
                    );                      
                }
           }, function(status) {
              console.log("permission not available");
            });
```

First I check if permission is granted if permission is not granted then ask for permission. For further details below link can be helpful

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions

Comment: This answer saved me. Thank you :)

Comment: I am glad that helped you.